# How to convert Spring <form:checkboxes> to AngularJS equivalent?

Tags: spring, angularjs, checkbox

I am migrating segments of Spring MVC code into AngularJS and hit the following problem:
In Spring, there is a nice tag that will take a Collection (or Map) of items and a property path to magically generate a list of checkboxes and have the selected ones checked;

```
<form:checkboxes path="selectedItems" items="${items}" />
```

where **selectedItems** is a List of value and **items** is Map of value and name.

Yes I can display all the checkboxes using this code:

```
<span ng-repeat="(key, value) in items" >
    <input type="checkbox" ng-value="key" > <label class="label" >{{value}}</label>
</span>
```

But the trick is how we can auto select the checkboxes based on the values in the **selectedItems** and then bind it when the user select/unselect other items?

Answer (score 2):

Directive give your html tag more power. I wrote a simple directive which will take a property "items" to generate a list of checkboxes and checked the selected ones according to item's status.

**HTML: define data in your controller and add tag < checkboxes >**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angular test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <div ng-controller="CheckboxesCtrl">
        <checkboxes items="items"></checkboxes>
        <button ng-click="changeData()">change data</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**App.js define controller and directive**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('CheckboxesCtrl',function($scope){
    //fake data
    $scope.items = [{label:"A",checked:true},{label:"B",checked:true},{label:"C",checked:false}];
    //data binding test
    $scope.changeData = function(){
        $scope.items[0].checked=false;
        $scope.items[0].label="changed A";
    } 
});

//checkboxes directive
app.directive('checkboxes',function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope:{
            items: "="
        },
        template: '<div ng-repeat="item in items">'+
                  '<input type="checkbox" ng-value="{{item.label}}" ng-checked="item.checked" />'+
                  ' <lable class="label"> {{item.label}} </label>'+
                  '</div>'
    };
});
```

I used ng-checked directive to process checkbox status binding. You could **try my test [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gm4pH/).**

Hope this is helpful for you.